# Do all Win32 registred events (RegisterHotKey, ...) get cleaned up after process dies?

Tags: windows, winapi

Do all events / callbacks registered via common Win32 APIs such as [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) etc. get cleaned up after the process that created them dies?

I suppose that yes but just want to be 100 % sure that there's nothing left after my App closes even in cases when my own cleanup didn't finish properly.

Comment: How would you modify your application, in case the OS didn't clean up after you?

Comment: Put more effort into cleanup reliability I suppose. Anyway, I'd also like to know that just because of I'm frankly quite curious.

Comment: Well, what do you expect to happen when you press the hotkey after your program terminated?  It is not going to blue-screen but you can't really tell the difference between "got cleaned-up" and "it can see it isn't there anymore".  But yes, it doesn't suck.

Comment: Just because you can't tell the difference doesn't mean there's no difference. Idk, it could e.g. hold the HotKey reserved and not allow other apps to register it for some weird legacy reason. I fully expect that it doesn't suck but we're talking about Win32 API so I'd rather be absolutely sure than just almost sure. (I don't mean to bash on Win32 API but it has some weird because-of-legacy-support quirks here and there).

Comment: Still, I don't get the question. You already know, that it's good practice to clean up. So just use RAII and you don't have to worry about any leaks. Unless you also want to guard against anything that causes an SEH exception, which is generally not worth it. However, rest assured, that with the amount of crap that runs on Windows all the time, the OS is fairly capable of cleaning up resources from crashed processes.

Comment: It's not only the practical side of things that interest me. I'd also like to know what is guaranteed to be cleaned up and the general guidelines for stateless win32 API calls.

Comment: Unless someone from Microsoft chimes in, the closest thing you'll get to a concrete answer on this is probably this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Notrl really much point in cleaning up since the OS will do so.